# How to add a gateway subnet to Vnet that contains VMs on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, vnet

My existing Vnet has a default subnet: 10.0.1.0/24

And I have a VM in it with IP address: 10.0.1.8

Now I want to add a gateway subnet so that I can connect web app to it, and the web app should be able to use the VM's private IP to access it.

But when I try to add a gateway subnet, I can't specify 10.0.1.0/24 because it overlaps with the default. I can't specify 10.0.0.0/24 either because the VM is not within this range.

How do I do it, then?

Comment: is this issue faced when you do VNet integration with web app?

Comment: @Aravind, yes. I'm trying to integrate an existing web app with an existing VNet

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a gateway subnet that uses the same address space (10.0.1.0/24) as VNet.

If you original subnet has a smaller address space (ie: /26, /28) then you can add a gateway subnet using that format.

If you original subnet is using the whole address space (ie: /24) then a work around will be to add a new address space to the VNet and add new subnets on that address to the VNet splitting them up correctly.